# ODE second order without variable coefficient

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I need some help ;
I have this ODE:
$$
y''= 2y^3
$$
We're asked to find a solution for it but I have no clue as we have never had such a thing in class. Can anyone help please ?

**Edit:** The initial conditions are $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=1$.

Comment: Suggestion: Multiply both sides by $y'$ and note that $y' y'' = (\frac{1}{2}y'^{2})'$.

Comment: A hint - $y'' = y'\frac{d y'}{dy}$ how does this help you? or alternatively one could multiple both sides by $y'$ and resolve into a single derivative.

Comment: I assume that he has something like $y'(x_0) = y(x_0) = 0$ to get rid of constants ;).

Comment: Yeah we have y(0) = 1 and y'(0)=1

Comment: But I still don't get it sorry

Comment: The solution is given below - just now $C=0$ to satisfy the condition that $y' = y=1$ for some point.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Multiply by $2y'$ to get

$$2y'' y' =4y^3 y'$$
which gives by integration

$$(y')^2=y^4+C $$

You can finish